# C# + Windows CE + Multiline & Align label

Tags: alignment, compact-framework, label, windows-ce, multiline

I need to make a multiline label with vertical and horizontal alignment and I don't know how I can do it !

I have found a way to make any control multiline with this function :

```
    private const int BS_MULTILINE = 0x00002000;
    private const int BS_CENTER = 0x00000300;
    private const int BS_VCENTER = 0x00000C00;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    [DllImport("coredll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("coredll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    public static void MakeControlMultiline(Control control) {
        IntPtr hwnd = control.Handle;
        int currentStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        int newStyle = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, currentStyle | /*BS_CENTER | BS_VCENTER | */BS_MULTILINE);
    }
```

The "BS_CENTER | BS_VCENTER" is in comment since it doesn't work !

So I try to make a customControl where I realise both alignments, like this :

```
public partial class ImproveLabel : Control {
    ...
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe) {
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        // text
        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        drawFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), drawFormat);
        // Calling the base class OnPaint
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
```

The strange thing here is that if I put both alignements to "Center", the multiline doesn't work anymore but if there is only the vertical alignment to "Center" and the horizontal alignment to "near", the multiline works.

I don't understand why it works this way but I need help to figure how I can get the 3 attributes working at the same time !

Answer (score 0):

The code below is straight out of the [P/Invoke SetWindowLong](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.setwindowlong) example.

```
private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const int BS_CENTER = 0x00000300;
private const int BS_VCENTER = 0x00000C00;
private const int BS_MULTILINE = 0x00002000;

public static void SetButtonStyle(Button ctrl)
{
    IntPtr hWnd;
    int style;

   // ctrl.Capture = true;
    // hWnd = GetCapture();
    // ctrl.Capture = false;

   // Comment below and uncomment above if using Visual Studio 2003
   hWnd = ctrl.Handle;

    style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (style | BS_CENTER | BS_VCENTER | BS_MULTILINE));

    ctrl.Refresh();
}
```

It looks about exactly like yours, but I have not tested it personally.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same code and it didn't work on Compact Framework (I try to add the ctrl.Refresh() but it didn't change anything).

No one have an idea about this issue ?